# JavaScript XMLHttprequests

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I got this example demonstrating AJAX from Stoyan Stefanovs *Object Oriented JavaScript* at page 275. In this example, he is requesting three different files. I have a couple questions if any of you can help.

1. What is  `xhr.send('')` doing? Why do we need it? I thought GET in the line before was establishign contact with the server, so why this send?
   *(The other questions relate to the closure that I don`t fully understand...)*
2. what exactly is getting passed as a paramater to `function(myxhr)`?
3. regarding the anonymous function, which has (xhr) passed as a parameter, can you explain at what point in the program xhr gets passed to the anonymous function? For example, is it after `xhr.open` has taken place?
4. why is function(myxhr) necessary? If it`s to create closure, why is closure necessary here?
5. is parameter `(xhr)` of the anonymous function getting passed as parameter `myxhr` in  `function(myxhr)` once the anonymous function is called?
6. if 5 is true--that `xhr` is passed as a parameter to `function(myxhr)`--why is it necessary to change the parameter name from `xhr` to `myxhr`?

Sample code:

```
function request(url, callback){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = (function(myxhr){
    return function() {
      callback(myxhr);
    }
  })(xhr);
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send('');
}

request (
  'http://www.phpied.com/files/jsoop/content.txt',
  function (o){
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = o.responseText;
  }
);

request(
  'http://www.phpied.com/files/jsoop/content.html',
  function(o) {
    document.getElementById('html').innerHTML = o.responseText;
  }
);

request(
  'http://www.phpied.com/files/jsoop/content.xml',
  function(o){
    document.getElementById('xml').innerHTML =
    o.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('root')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is xhr.send('') doing? Why do we
>   need it? I thought GET in the line
>   before was establishign contact with
>   the server, so why this send? (The
>   other questions relate to the closure
>   that I don`t fully understand...)

Open just sets up the request. Send actually sends it. When you make a POST request you need to pass the to send.

> what exactly is getting passed as a
>   paramater to function(myxhr)?

The content of the variable `xhr`.

> regarding the anonymous function,
>   which has (xhr) passed as a parameter,
>   can you explain at what point in the
>   program xhr gets passed to the
>   anonymous function? For example, is it
>   after xhr.open has taken place?

As soon as the function is called (which is immediately as the definition is followed by `()`).

> why is function(myxhr) necessary? If
>   it`s to create closure, why is closure
>   necessary here?

It isn't. Even if the `xhr` variable wasn't locally scoped to the `request` function (which it is) then it could be accessed via `this`.

> is parameter (xhr) of the anonymous
>   function getting passed as parameter
>   myxhr in function(myxhr) once the
>   anonymous function is called?

Yes.

> if 5 is true--that xhr is passed as a
>   parameter to function(myxhr)--why is
>   it necessary to change the parameter
>   name from xhr to myxhr?

It isn't. You can reuse the variable name at different scopes. It makes it less confusing though.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful resource to understand this is [XMLHHTPRequest Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN and [Using XMLHTTPReuqestobject](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html), but for brevity I try to answer your questions shortly.

1. xhr.send() ; issues the request to the URL through Open method.
2. XMLHTTPRequest object is passed as function parameter `function(myxhr)`
3. 'xhr' gets passed to the function when the request's status is changed after some response is received.
4. 'myxhr' is only the name of paramter that you can change as u wish but the object passed is of type XMLHttpResponse.
5. Yes
6. It is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - What is `xhr.send('')` doing?

It sends the request to the server. No network activity occurs before `send()` is called.

> 1.a - Why do we need it? I thought GET in the line before was establishing contact with the server, so why this send?

Because `open()` does not communicate with the server. It merely *prepares* the request object.

> 2 - what exactly is getting passed as a paramater to `function(myxhr)`?

The object `xhr` is passed to that function.

```
(function(myxhr){ /* ... */ })(xhr);
//-----------------------------^^^
//  define the function...    | ...and call it immediately
```

> 3 - regarding the anonymous function, which has (xhr) passed as a parameter, can you explain at what point in the program xhr gets passed to the anonymous function? For example, is it after xhr.open has taken place?

It gets passed immediately. The `function(myxhr)` has no other purpose in life than constructing and returning its result (which just happens to be another function), so its entire lifetime is the single statement in which it is defined and called immediately.

> 4 - why is function(myxhr) necessary? If it`s to create closure, why is closure necessary here?

In fact, the extra closure is not necessary. It's superfluous. This is equivalent (and it also creates a closure):

```
function request(url, callback){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = (function() {
      callback(xhr);
  });
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send('');
}
```

The closure is necessary so the callback function which is registered to the `readystatechange` event has some context to run in. A closure is always created automatically whenever a function is defined. It preserves the variables that were in scope at the time the function was defined: The above preserves the meaning of `xhr` and `callback` (and `url`, too!) in the inner function, even though it is not clear *when* the callback function is going to be executed.

> 5 - is parameter `(xhr)` of the anonymous function getting passed as parameter `myxhr` in `function(myxhr)` once the anonymous function is called?

Yes, it is passed when the anonymous "outer" function is called (see 3).

> 6 - if 5 is true--that xhr is passed as a parameter to function(myxhr)--why is it necessary to change the parameter name from xhr to myxhr?

It is not necessary, but less confusing than using the same variable name everywhere. Compare:

```
var f = (function(i) {
  /* outer scope i = 4 */
  return (function(i) {
    /* inner scope i = 8 */
    return i;
  })(i + 4);
})(4);

// now f is 8
```

However, if you want to use the "outer" `i` in the "inner" function, you'd have to use something else than `i` as the parameter name for the inner function.